# Delphi FMX TCalendar - Disable Weekends

Tags: android, ios, delphi, calendar, firemonkey

Is it possible to disable certain days from the FMX TCalendar component?
e.g. Weekends
It would also be good if they could be highlited that they are disabled e.g. days 14 and 15 in the image below

[image]

I can kind of get it disabled by adding a rectangle onto a listboxitemstyle with the hit test turned on 
This is what i did for the image above

```
procedure TForm1.cal1DayClick(Sender: TObject);
var sTemp : String;
begin
  cal1.StylesData['days.Selected.StyleLookup'] := 'ListBoxItemstyleCust';
end;
```

but i don't know how to access the styleslistbox items on the creation of the item and even if this is the way i should be doing it

Comment: Did Embarcadero create a updated FMX TCalendar for 10.3 with an better method than the answers given years ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time digging around this is a quick explanation of what i found
[Source code here](https://github.com/dangas56/MyCalStackOverflow)

In the folder
\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\source\fmx
There is a FMX.Calendar.Style.pas file

I have copied that file into the same location as my project and renamed it to My.FMX.Calendar.Style.pas

I have also renamed TStyledCalendar to TMyStyledCalendar, then changed the initialization and finalization from

```
initialization
  TPresentationProxyFactory.Current.Register(TCalendar, TControlType.Styled, TStyledPresentationProxy<TMyStyledCalendar>);
finalization
  TPresentationProxyFactory.Current.Unregister(TCalendar, TControlType.Styled, TStyledPresentationProxy<TMyStyledCalendar>);
end.

initialization
  TPresentationProxyFactory.Current.Unregister(TCalendar, TControlType.Styled, TStyledPresentationProxy<TStyledCalendar>);
  TPresentationProxyFactory.Current.Register(TCalendar, TControlType.Styled, TStyledPresentationProxy<TMyStyledCalendar>);
finalization
  TPresentationProxyFactory.Current.Unregister(TCalendar, TControlType.Styled, TStyledPresentationProxy<TMyStyledCalendar>);
```

also added FMX.Calendar.Style into the uses section
in the procedure FillDays; created a new procedure

```
  procedure ChangeStyle(aDay : TDateTime;Item: TDayItem);
  var wDay : Word;
  begin
    wDay := DayOfWeek(aDay-1);
    if (wDay = DaySaturday) or (wday = DaySunday) then begin
      item.Enabled := false;
      if (Item.StyleLookup <> 'MyListBoxItemstyle') then
        Item.StyleLookup := 'MyListBoxItemstyle';
    end else begin
      if (Item.StyleLookup <> '') then
        Item.StyleLookup := '';
    end;
  end;
```

and added the ChangeStyle( Item.Date, Item); to the following FillDaysOfPreviousMonth; FillDaysOfCurrentMonth; FillDaysOfNextMonth;

added a Styles to match MyListBoxItemstyle

[image: Styled Calendar]

after playing with the styles got it to look something like this
[image: Styled Calendar v2]