# Highlight Cell in FMX.TCalendar based off dates

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I have seen this post about how to highlight the cell but I cant find a DRAW in the source for FMX.TCalendar:

[is there a way to highlight cell/s in a TCalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62912484/)

What I am wanting to do is to be able to change all backgrounds to grey where `date < Today()`, then also have an option where I can do something like  `Function DisableCalendarDate(SOMEDATE);` and it would change that date to a grey background.

I can't find any way to do this. Maybe there is no way?

Comment: The post you linked to is for VCL, not for FMX

Comment: No easy customization like there is for the VCL calendar. Modifying the FMX one seems like an approach some have taken. Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770484/delphi-fmx-tcalendar-disable-weekends Another approach is mentioned in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744435/is-there-a-way-to-select-highlight-a-date-range-series-using-delphi-10-3-fmx-tca?rq=2

Comment: @Brian I agree style seems to be the way to go,  but having never done this, nor do I know if you can apply different styles for different dates and have them show up together is very confusing.  I will look into more the styles. but as of now its not clicking.